# Vuejs watching an object then execute a method fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I want to watch a prop which is an object so i have

```
<script>
export default {
    watch:{
        filter: {
            handler:(newval)=> {
               console.log("i have new data",newval) //this works
               this.fetchData(); //throws an error
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
    props:{
        filter:{
            type:Object,
            required:true
        }
    },
    data: () => ({
        pagination: {},
        items: []
    }),
    methods:{
        fetchData(){
            console.log("am fetching the data");
        }
    }
}
```

The above watcher works as the console.log displays the new value but i cannot execute a method as on the watch am getting an error Error in callback for watcher "filter": "TypeError: _this.fetchData is not a function". How can i execute a method on a deep watcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move Arrow function to simple function for `handler method`. Change `handler:(newval)=> {` to `handler: function (newval) {`:

[Vue.js docs:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as created: () => console.log(this.a) or vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod()).

```js
handler: function (newval) {
  console.log("i have new data",newval) //this works
  this.fetchData(); // it should work
},
```

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/ddg#34361380 Arrow functions have a different scoping than the “function” keyword, so your `this` is not what you expect with an arrow function. That’s the explanation of why Vue says to not use arrow functions.